# Composer - PHP check if composer.json need update

Tags: php, json, composer-php

Would like to ask, I made a simple php script to auto deploy from bitbucket when new set of code is being pushed to the repository which work fine. but from time to time there will be changes made to the `composer.json` file. So what I've done at this moment is by calling `exec('composer update')` every time the PHP script is being fired, which could be time consuming even though there are no changes made to the `composer.json` file.

Is there any way that I can call PHP to check if the `composer.json` file has been changed then only execute `exec('composer update')` ?

Comment: Why do you need to run `composer update` when "the PHP script is being fired"? Why not use `composer install` in your pipelines, as recommended everywhere? Also, is this problem really related to [tag:json]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can call PHP to check if the composer.json file has been changed then only execute exec('composer update') ?

I would suggest to do a history check of just one file from the repo by using "git diff" or compare/check the modification date of the file.

Examples:

- `git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD~50 -- ./composer.json`

  - check if composer.json was changed within the last 50 commits (HEAD)
- `git --no-pager diff --name-only origin/master~15 -- ./composer.json`

  - check if composer.json was changed within the last 15 commits (master branch)

If the file name is returned, then the file was changed within the commit range.

You might need to change the number of commits the diff goes back in the history to look for a change, but here is a rough draft to get you started:

```
<?php

function fileChanged() {
    $cmd = 'git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD~50 -- ./composer.json';
    exec($cmd, $output);
    return ($output[0] === 'composer.json') ? true : false;
}

if(fileChanged()) {
   exec('composer update');
} else {
   echo 'Found no change to "composer.json" with 50 commits. Skipping "composer update"';
}
```

---

Also for an auto-deployment pushing the `composer.lock` file to the repo and switching from running `composer update` to `composer install` could help, because Composer wouldn't need to do dependency resolution and version lookups, which improves deployment speed.

Running `composer install` will:

- Check, if a `composer.lock` exists

  - If not, do a `composer update` to create it
- If `composer.lock` exists, install the specified versions from the lock file

Running `composer update` will:

- Check `composer.json`
- Determine the latest versions to install based on your version specs
- Install the latest versions
- Update `composer.lock` to reflect the latest versions installed

Sidenote: I remember a similar or pretty close feature request (`--install-only-if-changed`) on the Github tracker: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3888.

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively, we could use the combination of `sha1sum` + `git` + `bash` script to check if `composer.json` need update. Let's create bash script with content

```
#!/bin/bash

git pull -q --ff-only

repoName=${PWD##*/} # Get current folder name
checkFile=/tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12
if [[ ! -f $checkFile || $(sha1sum -c ${checkFile} 2> /dev/null | grep FAILED | awk "{print \$2}") == *"FAILED"* ]]; then
    composer update
    retVal=$?
    if [[ $retVal -eq 0 ]]; then
        sha1sum composer.json > ${checkFile}
    fi
fi
```

And then grant an appropriate permission (e.g. 700) to this script. Every time you push to the repository, run this script under `/your/project/path` where your code is stored.

The script basically does:

- Running `git pull` every time a new set of code pushed
- For the first time run, `sha1sum` command output to `/tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12` with content looks like something similar below

```
 20379304c5944d13ef62f01edefa6ee3277a9e8c  composer.json
```

- From the next runs, `sha1sum -c /tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12` is checking the SHA-1 checksum in the file. If it returns `FAILED`, it means your composer.json is changed. The script runs `composer update` and adds a new SHA-1 checksum into the `/tmp/composer_hash_${repoName}.sha12`. Otherwise, it does nothing.

---

However, as Jens A. Koch has mentioned, I also would recommend we run `composer update` locally when we have something to change in `composer.json`, `composer.lock` has been updated to the latest then so that we can push the `composer.lock` file to the repository.

And then, we could switch to use `composer install` in the script I've written above. It's more ideal when it comes to auto-deployment and also improve pipeline speed.

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate question of the other, please flag it as such. If not, please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to other questions